# How to trigger Omniauth-Facebook correctly (/auth/facebook) from API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, omniauth-facebook

I have been struggling for a long while trying to determine the correct approach to use the omniauth-facebook gem.

I am running my API on port 3001 while my frontend (in my case coded on ReactJS) is running on port 3000. As per what I have been researching, this is a common issue but there is not a clear answer nor documentation here. I am not expecting to use any additional SDK as I understand that this gem should handle all I need to simply login through FB.

When manually running on the browser `http://localhost:3001/auth/facebook`, I can see on Rails console that route is being hit and things are moving forward as expected; also, I am seeing that callback route is hit and I am getting back a JSON with UID, client and auth_token.

However, when trying to reach this through my react app, I am getting a CORS error. I am simply making an AXIOS.get(/auth/facebook) which gets routed into my API as I have configured the proxy to pass calls received on my frontend into the API. My console seems to be hit by my request as I am seeing the following:

[image]

However, on the Chrome console, I am seeing a CORS issue as per the following image:

[image]

For sure, I have already tried adding the following code snippet and still getting the same error:

[image]

Having said this, could someone answer me the following questions:

- which is the expected way to trigger the initial call into /auth/facebook route? Kindly do not FW me to read the main repo doc as it does not say this solution there.
- has someone solved the present issue on a way which is not by adding a link into `http://localhost:3001/auth/facebook`? Would this be a correct approach? It sounds weird to me.